# Using d-i command to install packages for unatttended installation

Tags: 18.04, package-management, system-installation, ssh

I have written the following lines in a preseed.cfg file for an unattended Ubuntu 18.04 desktop installation.

```
# Packages, Mirrors, Image
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-image-amd64
d-i mirror/country string US
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
```

After the installation, I ran `dpkg -l | grep ssh` and only see `libssh-4` and `openssh-client` packages. I don't see any problem with the `d-i` commands. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Ubiquity installer (the desktop image) then the wiki states that `pkgsel` and `tasksel` preseed settings will be ignored.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation

```
Preseeding keys for the following installer components will not be used in Ubiquity, usually because they do not fit with Ubiquity's mode of operation:
    netcfg
    LVM and RAID partitioning
    base-installer
    pkgsel/tasksel
    finish-install
```